# Python py2exe executable attributeerror

Tags: python, executable, attributeerror, py2exe, setup.py

I am trying to create an executable for a script I have already written.  It will be used by a coworker who doesn't have python on their machine, so I want to create an executable to make their life easier.  I'm currently just trying to get py2exe to work and create an executable for a simple script that simply prints hello world and the constant e from the math module (just to get an idea for how py2exe works).

My setup script is as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import math

setup(
console=[{'script':'hello.py'}],
options={
    'py2exe':{
        'packages' : ['math'],
        'bundle_files':1
    },
},
version='1.0.0'
```

)

where hello.py is simply:

```
import math
print('hello world!')
print(f'Here is e: {math.exp(1)}')
```

The error comes from this stack after I call "python setup.py py2exe" in cmd

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    setup(
  File ".\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    return run_commands(dist)
  File ".\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
    dist.run_commands()
  File ".\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File ".\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File ".\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File ".\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 192, in run
    self._run()
  File ".\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 273, in _run
    builder.build()
  File ".\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 250, in build
    self.build_archive(exe_path)
  File ".\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 490, in build_archive
    base = dist_path.rsplit('\\', 1)[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rsplit'
```

Answer (score 0):

To covert a .py file to .exe you need to install auto-py-to-exe

Windows

```
pip install auto-py-to-exe
```

After it is installed, open cmd then type

```
auto-py-to-exe
```

Then specify the path of the script and the location where you want to save the .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty fix - I modified runtime.py (listed in the source of your exception) and added a check to continue if dist_path is None. It worked to compile a console application, but this might have unintended consequences for others.

```
if mod.__path__ is not None and mod.__name__[0] != '_': # attempt to select valid packages
    try:
        dist = pkg_resources.get_distribution(mod.__name__)
        dist_path = dist._provider.egg_info
    
        # Added if statement
        if dist_path == None:
            continue
                    
        base = dist_path.rsplit('\\', 1)[0]
        name = dist_path.split(base + '\\')[1]
```