# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rsplit' in py2exe

Tags: python, compilation, py2exe

I hope my problem hasn't already been solved. I'm having a problem compiling my python program into an executable. The program I want to compile is with tkinter and I use py2exe to compile. Here is my code for compiling:

```
from py2exe import freeze

freeze(
    windows=[{'script': 'fichier.py'}],
    options={
        'bundle_files': 1,
        'compressed': 1,
        'dll_excludes': ['tcl85.dll', 'tk85.dll'],
        'includes': ['os', 'ctypes', 'tkinter', 'PIL', 'tkinter.font']
            },
    zipfile='test.zip'
)
```

This returns the error to me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\henzo\OneDrive\Documents\python\auto_fond\setup.py", line 27, in <module>
    zipfile='test.zip'
  File "C:\EduPython\App\lib\site-packages\py2exe\__init__.py", line 176, in freeze
    builder.build()
  File "C:\EduPython\App\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 273, in build
    self.build_archive(libpath, delete_existing_resources=True)
  File "C:\EduPython\App\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 479, in build_archive
    base = dist_path.rsplit('\\', 1)[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rsplit'
```

In addition, I can't run my .exe after executing the program (I don't know if this is linked to the error). I would like to use the py2exe module because the other modules such as pyinstaller or cx_freezer do not work or tell me that there is a virus.

Thanks in advance.

Programmeurdu33

I'm looking for a solution to my problem. I've already looked everywhere but can't find anything.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73353642/6394617)?

Comment: Good evening. Yes, I have already tested but when I want to remove the cmd window it detects a virus.

Comment: Well, in the [source code](https://github.com/py2exe/py2exe/blob/master/py2exe/runtime.py), line 483,   `dist_path = dist._provider.egg_info` must be getting assigned `None`. I don't know what `egg_info` is, but it seems like one of the modules you're using doesn't provide it. You could add print statements above that line in py2exe's runtime.py to see which is the offending module.